# Removing lines based on conditions

Tags: sas

I want to remove rows (or observations) in SAS based on certain conditions: If the i-th name in the name column is the same as (i+1)-th name AND the i-th date is the same as the (i+1)-th date, remove line (i+1)-th. I also want to delete rows i+2, i+3, etc. if the entries in these columns are the same as in row i. But, this could maybe done iteratively if the previous rows were deleted.

I am fairly new to SAS. I know I should use some form of loop but I can't figure out how to use it. This question has been bugging me a couple of days. I hope someone could help me out.

Comment: If there will i+2 equals to i+1 and i, what you need to do with this observation?(and of course i+3 and so on)

Comment: Good question, maybe should have added that. I will now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a processing task that can be solved using a `BY` statement and automatic `FIRST.` by-group variable flag.

```
data want;
  set have;
  by date name;
  if first.name;
run;
```

If the by-group rows are contiguous but not sorted you can add the `NOTSORTED` option to the `BY` statement.

You will need to use additional variables in the by-group statement if the actual data structure has additional 'parent' categorical variables that further group name:dates (such as, say `insuranceCompany` and `policyGroup`, or `team`).

Answer (score 1):

Test data:

```
+-----------+--------+-------+
| date      | name   | value |
+-----------+--------+-------+
| 10MAY2019 | param1 | 1     |
+-----------+--------+-------+
| 10MAY2019 | param1 | 2     |
+-----------+--------+-------+
| 10MAY2019 | param1 | 2     |
+-----------+--------+-------+
| 10MAY2019 | param2 | 1     |
+-----------+--------+-------+
| 10MAY2019 | param3 | 1     |
+-----------+--------+-------+
| 10MAY2019 | param4 | 1     |
+-----------+--------+-------+
| 10MAY2019 | param5 | 1     |
+-----------+--------+-------+
| 10MAY2019 | param5 | 1     |
+-----------+--------+-------+
```

The idea of my solution is to generate key by concatenating params and retain it.

```
data test;
format date date9.;
input name $6. value date yymmdd10.;
datalines4;
param1   1 2019-05-10
param1   2 2019-05-10
param1   2 2019-05-10
param2   1 2019-05-10
param3   1 2019-05-10
param4   1 2019-05-10
param5   1 2019-05-10
param5   1 2019-05-10
;;;;
run;

data want(drop=key);
   set test;
   retain key;
   if _N_ = 1 then do;
      key = strip(name) || strip(put(date,date9.));
      output;
   end;
   else if key ne strip(name) || strip(put(date,date9.)) then do;
      key = strip(name) || strip(put(date,date9.));
      output;
   end;
run;
```

Result:

```
+-----------+--------+-------+
| date      | name   | value |
+-----------+--------+-------+
| 10MAY2019 | param1 | 1     |
+-----------+--------+-------+
| 10MAY2019 | param2 | 1     |
+-----------+--------+-------+
| 10MAY2019 | param3 | 1     |
+-----------+--------+-------+
| 10MAY2019 | param4 | 1     |
+-----------+--------+-------+
| 10MAY2019 | param5 | 1     |
+-----------+--------+-------+
```